# Require file dynamically

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I got the following files

```
const theFirstService = require('theFirstService');
const theSecondService = require('theSecondService');
```

Every one of the `services` above have a `method` called `process()`. 
Now i receive an object as follows

```
  obj = {
        uniqueKey:'theFirst'
    }
```

How can i call `process()` dynamically ?

Something like `obj[uniqueKey]Service.process()`

Well the above ofcourse does not work

Comment: don't know what you're asking. what is this ? `obj[uniqueKey]Service.process()` ?

Comment: "Now i receive an object" - how do you received that object and whati is it connection with services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an object with both services as values to keys with the names of what you want to load in:

```
const services = {
    theFirst: require('theFirstService'),
    theSecond: require('theSecondService')
}
```

and then with your data you can do the following:

```
obj = {
    uniqueKey:'theFirst'
}

services[obj.uniqueKey].process();
```